# Receiving AJAX jQuery array in c#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I have a JSON array like this:

```
  "{structChangeList : '[{"structChange":{"id":"Level1.Second","parentId":"Level1.First","date":"2011-01-01"}}]'"
```

or

"[{"structChangeList":{"id":"Level1.Second","parentId":"Level1.First","date":"2011-01-01"}}]"

and various other variationd which I am trying to pick up with a web method like

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string receiveStructureUpdates3(List<StrutureData> structChangeList)
    {

        return "Hello World";
    }
```

where StructureData is:

```
[DataContract]
public class StrutureData
{
    [DataMember]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string parentId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string date { get; set; }
}
```

It works fine when I try to pick up a non array like:

"{"structChange":{"id":"Level1.Second","parentId":"Level1.First","date":"2011-01-01"}}"

with:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string receiveStructureUpdates2(StrutureData structChange)
    {
    }
```

But I can't get the array working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

To use an array/list, change:

```
"{"structChange":{"id":"Level1.Second","parentId":"Level1.First","date":"2011-01-01"}}"
```

To

```
{"structChange": [{"id":"Level1.Second","parentId":"Level1.First","date":"2011-01-01"}]}
```

Because .Net is looking for `structChage`, it wants to find that first. Since `structChange` is a `List` the value for that key needs to be an array.

Comment: I've already got that code but I don't want to pick up a string in JSON format and then deserialise it, I want to pick up the json directly

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to send data to an action in the controller

```
data: "{someField : [[\"Level1.Second\",\"Level1.First\",\"2011-01-01\"]] }
```